# Python Dict to numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a python dictionary with keys `(0,1,2....n)` with each key holding the location co-ordinates in a tuple such as

```
{0:(x1,y1), 1:(x2,y2), 2:(x3,y3), ....., n-1:(xn,yn)}
```

I want to create a multidimensional array like

```
coordinates= np.array([
       [x1, y1],
       [x2, y2],
        ...
       [xn, yn]
       ])
```

I have tried using `array = numpy.array(vehPositions.values())` but could not get the expected result.

Comment: Why didn't `numpy.array(vehPositions.values())` work? Are the values in different order or wrong values?

Comment: I only get a array of type (object) like
`array(dict_values([(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...]))`. If i use  `array(x)`, it returns me **'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable**. If I do `array[x]`, it gives me **too many indices for array**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using python 3.x you should cast explicitly to `list` as the `values()`  method of `dict` will return a `dict_values` object.

You should do:

```
array = numpy.array(list(vehPositions.values()))
```

To create your list of lists from the tuple values in your dictionary and build your array, you will not need an explicit cast to `list`:

```
array = numpy.array([list(v) for v in vehPositions.values()])
```

Be careful to not use a generator expression as this will return an array containing a generator object:

```
>>> numpy.array(list(v) for v in vehPositions.values())
array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03B60AA8>, dtype=object)
```

The trial below demonstrates the procedure:

```
>>> d = {0: (1,2), 1: (3,4), 2: (5,6)}
>>> numpy.array([list(v) for v in d.values()])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```